# #1064 error in MySQL. utf8_general_ci with MRG_MYISAM engine

Tags: mysql, sql

I want create a database server online but i have a problem. My code is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `b10_16569036_frontonApp`.`fronton` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`Name` VARCHAR CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`number` INT NOT NULL ,
`cover` INT NOT NULL ,
`ligth` INT NOT NULL ,
`type` INT NOT NULL ,
`height` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`widht` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`lenght` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`latitude` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
`longitude` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
`status` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`time` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`price` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE = MRG_MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

But when I apply this code, this error appear:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL, `number`
>   INT NOT NULL, `cov' at line 1

I suppose that it is about utf8 and MRG_MYISAM engine but, what character set can i use? and what is the difference between utf8 and others?

i'm using phpMyAdmin to create this database.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please read the error message carefully—invalid code starts right at `CHARACTER`, it has nothing to do with your encoding choice. As Prerak points out in his answer, you forgot the `VARCHAR` size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give a limit for `varchar`.
Change

```
Name VARCHAR CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
```

to

```
Name VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
```

You can change the limit asper your requirement. I have taken `100` for example.